# Как на время обработки результата запретить пользователю уходить со страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, form

Есть форма `html`, которая отправляет на сервер некоторую сгенерированную информацию, но, прежде чем ее отправить, обрабатывает и генерурует`pdf`. На генерацию и обработку уходит некоторое время от 8 до 27 секунд. 
Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь не мог покинуть страницу и нажать крестик

```
alert("Подождите, ваш результат еще обрабатывается");
```

до момента когда результат сформируется, отправится и запишется в бд на сервере и будет отправлен клиенту назад?

Comment: Врядли политика безопасности браузера позволит такое сделать. Скорее всего можно вывести некий диалог, аля "Вы уверены что хотите покинуть страницу ?"

Comment: Никак нельзя сделать и слава Богу!

Comment: @dev_null и как это сделать?

Comment: Я переформулирую вопрос: *как запретить пользователю выключать компьютер*.

Comment: @Igor улыбнуло =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `window.onunload` и `window.onbeforeunload`

Пример:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  return "Данные не сохранены. Точно перейти?";
};
```

Comment: оно среагирует на момент загрузки страницы?

Comment: почитайте [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)

Comment: спасибо! А как его потом уже отпустить?)

Comment: вы вообще пробовали воспроизвести этот код? он подтвердит и уйдет

Comment: я про то, что не отпускать его пока страница грузится, а когда отчет уже сформирован - с Божьей помощью отпустить

Comment: вы всё равно никак принудительно удержать никого не сможете, будет лишь только оповещание о том, что он хочет покинуть страницу и данные будут не сохранены. Здесь всё зависит только от адекватности вашего пользователя. Добавьте еще какие-нибудь лаодеры чтоб было понятно что сейчас происходит. Честно говоря, ваш подход редко где используется и он очень сильно раздражает когда на него попадаешь.

Comment: конкретный вам пример: формирование с интерактивного `canvas` отчета с графиками и  таблицами в `pdf`. Релизовать можно только через специально предназначенные для этого библиотеки `js`, а это все просиходит не мгновенно и более того от 8 сек в зависимости от сложности отчета. Да, расчет идет только на адекватные пользователей, которые увидят надпись и подождут некоторое необходимое время

Comment: у меня `onbeforeunload``срабатывает, только если я вешаю событие на кнопку - так и должно быть?
`<button id="button" onclick="javascript:showModal()">Нажми на меня</button>`